# Oracle Apex downloading multiple blob data

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, apex

I am trying to create an app on apex that uploads and downloads blob items.  I have an interactive reports page and buttons for uploading and downloading. When these buttons clicked, they pop up modal dialog pages. Upload button opens up a dialog that has file select section in it. Download button opens up an interactive grid dialog that has row selector and file name columns in it. Uploading system is done. But when it comes to downloading I have an issue.

Now I know that apex is not letting us to download multiple blobs before zipping them into a single zip file. So my app needs a procedure for that. This procedure is in the processing section. Here is what I wrote for that task:

```
declare
    var_zip blob;
     
begin
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(
        p_collection_name => 'ZIP');
        
    begin
        for var_file in (select f_doc_filename, f_doc , seq_id
                         from apex_test_file_upload)
        loop
            APEX_ZIP.ADD_FILE (
                p_zipped_blob =>  var_zip,
                p_file_name   =>  var_file.f_doc_filename,
                p_content     => var_file.f_doc );
        end loop;
    exception when no_data_found then
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'No Files found!');
    end;
    APEX_ZIP.FINISH(
        p_zipped_blob => var_zip);
    APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER(
        p_collection_name => 'ZIP',
        p_blob001            => var_zip);
end;
```

Second, I need another procedure to download this created zip. This procedure is in the ajax callback section. Here is my code again for download:

```
declare
  var_mimetype varchar2(50) := 'application/zip';
  var_name varchar2(100) := to_char(current_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || '_files.zip';
  var_blob blob;
   
begin
    select blob001 into var_blob from apex_collections where collection_name = 'ZIP' and seq_id = 1;
     
    sys.htp.init;
    sys.owa_util.mime_header( var_mimetype, FALSE );
    sys.htp.p('Content-length: ' || sys.dbms_lob.getlength( var_blob));
    sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' || var_name || '"' );
    sys.htp.p('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');
    sys.owa_util.http_header_close;
    sys.wpg_docload.download_file( var_blob );
 
    apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
     
exception when apex_application.e_stop_apex_engine then
    NULL;    
end;
```

When I try to download the files it's not throwing any error. But it's not downloading anything either. So I debug the page with full trace. Then something like this showed up on the debug message data page : [debug_msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Rf2.png) and [debug_msg_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMyOI.png).

I think maybe selecting the items with row selector might be the problem but don't know.
am using oracle apex just for 3 weeks. So i am practically a beginner. Also i couldnt find any resources that are useful or current. So what might be my mistakes?